# WebSharper 3.4 with working HelloWorld example?

Tags: f#, websharper

The current `HelloWorld` example on [websharper.com](http://websharper.com) doesn't work anymore due to changes made in WebSharper 3.4. It now requires some attributes and other stuff to compile correctly.

I am just getting started with WebSharper and I would like to see a minimum (html+javascript client-side hello world) example that works. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the one on the front page? https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.ui.next.todolist.sample

Comment: @azium Still fails to compile and reactive UI is not really a minimum example

Answer (score 1):

The samples on the website use `Html.Client` (the HTML language soon to be retired in favor of UI.Next), so to run them you need to start from a template that isn't based on UI.Next.

Following the instructions [here](http://websharper.com/docs/running-snippets), I was able to run them without any issues, extra attributes, etc.